# Check if String contains any of the values present in String[] without using regex - Java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a String[] that has values that i need to find in the text entered into an EditText. I know how to do it using regex, but is there a way i can do it without regex.

```
public static String[] knownCombinations = new String[] { "IV", "IX", "XL",
            "CD", "CM" };
```

Now, if i enter, `MMMDCCIV`, how do I check if the string has any of the values from the String[]? or is iterating through the String[] and checking for each value among the string entered, is good enough approach?

For example:

```
String input = "MMMDCCIV";

for(int i = 0; i < knownCombinations.length; i++) {
  if(input.contains(knownCombinations[i])
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}
```

or is there a better approach?

Comment: Regex is not a good solution here. It's good that you don't want to use it :)

Comment: What is the problem exactly? "Good enough" is a relative term...

Comment: I meant, can it be done with any of the in-built methods in Java.

Comment: Another answer coming your way...hang on...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, as you command officer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over the array is the only way (though it may be written with less code using Java 8 Streams), but there's an error in your loop.
You should only return false after the loop ends without finding any match.

```
for(int i = 0; i < knownCombinations.length; i++) {
  if(input.contains(knownCombinations[i])
    return true;
}
return false;
```

That's assuming you require at least one of the array's elements to be contained in the input String (and not all of them).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over the array, you *could* iterate over the `input` String after adding the `knownCombinations` to a `Set`:

```
Set<String> knownSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(knownCombinations)); 
String input = "MMMDCCIV";

for (int i=0; i < input.length-1; ++i) {              // iterate over each 2-letter 
    if (knownSet.contains(input.substring(i, i+2)) {  // combination in the input
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

This is essentially the inverse of @Eran 's solution.  I would probably go with his approach because it is slightly easier to read, but I thought my answer was a good attempt to solve the problem with a different flavor.

Comment: Since, Eran was the first to answer, i accepted his answer. I upvoted your answer. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.

Comment: No worries...happy to answer your question ^ ^